# Уникальная страница для каждого "Объявления"

Tags: php, база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Есть сайт объявлений (Аналог авито и прочих).
При создании нового объявления(с добавлением в БД),нужна уникальная ссылка или физическая страница.

Как будет "правильнее" -создавать к каждому объявлению физ.страницу с занесением её URL в базу, или по щелчку на любое объявление передавать GET или POST и открывать одну (Page.php) страницу с переданными параметрами?
Как это реализовано на известных проектах Вк,авито и др.?

Comment: Для поисковых систем и людей, которые тыкают в ссылки, а не набирают url вручную - совершенно без разницы!

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такой механихм называют роутингом или маршрутизацией (англ. route). Он реализуется за счет настроек сервера (`nginx` или `apache`). В частности многие php фремфорки поставляются со своим файлом `.htaccess` в котором указаны правила перенаправления адресов.
Ниже пример этого файла для `laravel`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

В данном случае любой запрос обрабатываемый `apache` будет адресован на `index.php` и уже в его логике необходимо будет разбирать url и выбирать стратегию поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сказать как это сделано на ВК, или авитов. Но у меня реализовано на symfony это следующем образом.

1. Существует маршрут к примеру mycompany.com/ads/{id}. Где id это переменная.
2. Этот маршрут передаётся на контроллер и по id из базы выберется нужные мне объект.
3. Если объект найден открываем нужный нам шаблон к примеру ads_page и заполняем нужные нам поля на основании выбранного объекта.
4. Если объекта не существует то формируем исключения.